# Safari: Is there a way to prevent Inspect Element opening the console?

Tags: safari, console

I’ve used Safari as my main browser for web dev for years now and at some point fairly recently what I think of as the ‘mini’ console has started to open automatically whenever I right-click and select Inspect Element. I’m talking about the minimisable console here (highlighted in yellow below) rather than the dedicated Console tab.

I’m not sure if this is an intentional change in webkit but I find it very frustrating as the console portion opens up even if I’ve hidden it via the ▿ button previously, and it wastes valuable space.

Has anyone else run in to this or found a workaround? I’ve trawled through all of the Inspector settings and can’t see anything. Neither Chrome or Edge have started doing this with their Inspect Element features, but I’d prefer to stick with Safari if possible.

[image: Web inspector ‘mini’ console]

Comment: It appears not to be possible

Comment: I agree with @Ezekiel , there's no apparent way to do this. I only see one way to avoid seeing the console (as well as the rest of the developer tools) : disable developer tools completely; but that won't be a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I stumbled on the below ‘fix’ shortly after updating to 16.5 and it turns out that was the real solution. After updating to 16.5 closing the mini console by any method will persist.

Here’s the relevant change from the [Safari 16.5 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes/safari-16_5-release-notes#Web-Inspector):

> - Fixed “Selected element” console entry filling an entire row.
> - Fixed an issue causing the mini console to always opens when choosing “Inspect Element”, even if it was previously closed.

<s>This has been annoying me for weeks and predictably I’ve stumbled onto the solution 10 minutes after posting a question about it.</s>

The trick is *not* to use the minimise/▿ icon to hide the console – because why would that make sense when you want to get rid of something – it’s in fact the opposite: you need to click the maximise icon on the right to open the full console view. Afterwards you can Inspect Element to your heart’s content and the mini-console won’t reopen.

[image: Web inspector view with maximise button highlighted in yellow]

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Clicking "Expand" goes to the Console tab, and going back to "Elements" doesn't show it. But re-inspecting something new re-shows the mini console.

Comment: I don’t know what to tell you. Here’s a [screen recording](https://share.cleanshot.com/wBZyh51M) that shows it works for me.

Comment: Are you using Safari 16.5 or 16.4? Your fix does nothing on my machine with 16.4 and is not necessary on my machine with 16.5 so I wonder if some stuff has changed

Comment: Safari 16.5 here. I’ve been installing updates immediately in the hope one would address this, so maybe they finally (sort of) have. (Also perhaps it’s not necessary because you haven’t had the mini-console open before. For me, as soon as I’ve opened it it wants to stay open, even on 16.5.)

Comment: Hmm, I wonder what the difference is - there's definitely something odd going on since I've got two computers behaving differently.

Comment: I retested on a second machine and verified that 16.5 is the real fix. Having checked the release notes they confirm it. I’ve updated my answer.